# Spring Boot - Placeholder as a default value in YAML

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Is there a way to use a placeholder as a default value in a YAML file?

What I'm trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
key1: key1value
key2: ${ENV_PROPERTY_1:${key1}}
```

But the value I get against `key2` is `${key1}` instead of `key1value`.

Is there any way to do that?

p.s: It's a Spring Boot based project.

Comment: Thanks @Anthon for the correction.

Comment: You could use some templating mechanism to achieve that, but there is nothing in the YAML specification that makes a scalar starting with `$` anything special, so **YAML** cannot do this. So without some context (programming language, library, program) about what you are using, the answer is will be no

Comment: @Anthon its a Spring Boot based project.

Comment: Can you try “{ENV_PROPERTY_1:{{key1}}}”

Comment: `${ENV_PROPERTY_1:{{key1}}}` didn't worked either.

Comment: Try removing $ from the same

Comment: @RahulWagh if you remove $ then it will not be parsed as a placeholder altogether, so it definitely won't work.

Comment: nb: `${property1:${defaultProperty}}` is supported in spring's `@Value` annotation, so this might be a good starting point